# localhost image not showing up in asp.net listview

Tags: asp.net, localhost, imageurl

My web application retrieves the location of an image from database. I'd like to show the image in listview using image control. Although my database gives the correct location of my image, for some reason, my web application cannot render the image file. (When I put the same address in another image control, the image appears.) Does anybody have clue on this matter? Thanks in advance. My codes in listview are:

```
        <ItemTemplate>
            <td runat="server" style="">
                <asp:Image ID="albumImage" ImageURL = '<%# Eval("imgLocation") %>' runat="server" AlternateText= '<%# Eval("imgLocation") %>' /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="albmNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("albmName") %>' />
                <br />
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

HTML generated by the portion of my web application is:

```
           <td style="">
                <img id="ListView1_albumImage_0" src="C:\odaiba.png" alt="C:\odaiba.png" /><br />
                <span id="ListView1_albmNameLabel_0">tokyo trip</span>
                <br />
            </td>
```

Comment: Is `imgLocation` absolute or relative? What's the HTML produced by the snippet?

Comment: what is an example of the value of `imgLocation`?

Comment: imgLocation gives "C:\odaiba.png."

Comment: Unless this is some local only app you don't want to use `C:\`` for the actual path to anything. It should be a virtual path the the file within the app like `localhost/odaiba.png`

Comment: You are right. I just used C drive for testing purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than put the image at `C:\`, I would strongly urge you to make an `images` folder in your web project and update your database to refer to the images with a relative path: `images/odaiba.png`.

Comment: Wouldn't that slow down my web application if I have too many images? Is there no difference?

Comment: Your solution does work! I do not know why C drive was the problem, though.

Comment: File system URLs just don't work for web sites. You either want a full URL (http://localhost/images/odaiba.png), an absolute path (/images/odaiba.png) or relative to the location of the aspx page (images/odaiba.png for a file at the site root).